# Flutter - Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available

Tags: flutter, dart

[background_fetch: ^1.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)

I use the above plugin to execute a task for every 15 minutes even after terminate the app. But after adding the above library my app throws the error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://maven.google.com/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/Users/rsoft/StudioProjects/salezrobot/android/app/libs/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app > project :background_fetch
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

add this in `android/build.gradle`:

```
maven {
   url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
}
```

to `allprojects/repositories`, **NOT** to the `buildscript/repositories`

Comment: I had the same error and this one work for me, but invoke two notes:                             1.Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
2.Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md

Answer (score 1):

You first have to follow the setup below guides:

1. [IOS](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-IOS.md)
2. [ANDROID](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md)